# remove object if value is empty

Tags: javascript

array1 is an array of objects, so something like this:

```
0: {Group: 1, names: "Lastname1, Firstname1", id: 20000001}
1: {Group: 2, names: "Lastname2, Firstname2", id: 20000002}
2: {Group: 3, names: "Lastname3, Firstname3", id: 20000003}
```

array2 also  an array of objects, so something like this:

```
0: {id: "20000001", photo: ""}
1: {id: "20000001", photo: "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/4QB6RXhpZgAASUkqAAgAAA…9a1EtFKAnd09f/rVlwfdFbVw7LPIoOAGNYwjc/SIaxR//2Q=="}
2: {id: "20000002", photo: ""}
3: {id: "20000003", photo: ""}
4: {id: "20000004", photo: ""}
```

I want to get the photo value for a specific id based on array1. My array2 can have duplicate values of id, so I want to ignore the one with the empty string.

so at the end of the day, i want to return something like
`var image='/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/4QB6R...'`

Comment: Use array's `filter()`. Read here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter ...Come back to us if you're still having problem with it.

Comment: You can loop it and get only if the value is not empty, then exit loop if you are ok with one value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let arr = [{
    id: "20000001",
    photo: ""
  },
  {
    id: "20000001",
    photo: "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/4QB6RXhpZgAASUkqAAgAAA…9a1EtFKAnd09f/rVlwfdFbVw7LPIoOAGNYwjc/SIaxR//2Q=="
  },
  {
    id: "20000002",
    photo: ""
  },
  {
    id: "20000003",
    photo: ""
  },
  {
    id: "20000004",
    photo: ""
  }
]

function findItemByID(arr, id) {
  return arr.find((photoObj) => {
    return photoObj.photo.trim().length !== 0 && photoObj.id === id
  })
}

let photoObj = findItemByID(arr, "20000001");
console.log(photoObj.photo);
```

Comment: Can u please help me with this, I used your implementation.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53574769/display-pictures-based-on-specific-student-id

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to get the value you want. It will return the first value found. Empty strings are falser in javascript so you can write the find call back like:

```js
let arr = [
  {id: "20000001", photo: ""},
  {id: "20000001", photo: "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/4QB6RXhpZgAASUkqAAgAAA…9a1EtFKAnd09f/rVlwfdFbVw7LPIoOAGNYwjc/SIaxR//2Q=="},
  {id: "20000002", photo: ""},
  {id: "20000003", photo: ""},
  {id: "20000004", photo: ""}
]

let found = arr.find(item => item.photo && item.id === '20000001')
console.log(found.photo)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var array2 = [{id: "20000001", photo: ""},
{id: "20000001", photo: "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/4QB6RXhpZgAASUkqAAgAAA…9a1EtFKAnd09f/rVlwfdFbVw7LPIoOAGNYwjc/SIaxR//2Q=="},
{id: "20000002", photo: ""},
{id: "20000003", photo: ""},
{id: "20000004", photo: ""}];

var result = array2.filter(function(a){ return a.photo }).map(a => a.photo);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
function getForId(photos, id) {
    var tmp = photos.filter(ph => ph.id == id).filter(ph => ph.photo != "");
    if (tmp.length == 0) return undefined;
    return tmp[0];
}

...

x = getForId(array2, "20000001");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could map over (via `Array.map`) the main array and for each item use `Array.find` to get its `photo`. Then assign to the current item like this:

```js
const data = [{ Group: 1, names: "Lastname1, Firstname1", id: 20000001 }, { Group: 2, names: "Lastname2, Firstname2", id: 20000002 }, { Group: 3, names: "Lastname3, Firstname3", id: 20000003 } ]
const images = [ {id: "20000001", photo: ""}, {id: "20000001", photo: "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/4QB6RXhpZgAASUkqAAgAAA…9a1EtFKAnd09f/rVlwfdFbVw7LPIoOAGNYwjc/SIaxR//2Q=="}, {id: "20000002", photo: ""} ]

const result = data.map(x => {
  let img = images.find(i => x.id == i.id && i.photo != '') 
  if(img) Object.assign(x, {photo: img.photo})
  return x
})
console.log(result)
```